# GeoPandas TypeError: geometries are not orderable (numpy: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Point' and 'Point')

Tags: python, geopandas, numpy, aggregation, grouping

I'm trying to group rows of a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html?highlight=geodataframe#geopandas.GeoDataFrame) based on a common `gid` value and aggregating two columns for which the values differ but I am facing this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in safe_sort(values, codes, na_sentinel, assume_unique, verify)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/sorting.py in nargsort(items, kind, ascending, na_position, key)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/geopandas/array.py in _values_for_argsort(self)
>
> TypeError: geometries are not orderable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> (...)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Point' and 'Point'

Here is the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/raw/Xbvr5CQT

And here's a piece of reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon

print(pd.__version__)      # prints 1.1.4
print(gpd.__version__)     # prints 0.8.2
print(shapely.__version__) # prints 1.7.1

# this dataframe has plenty of other attributes (not shown here),
# but they are always the same for the same gid, I only kept 
# the city-attribute one for the purpose of the example:    
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'gid': [1,1,1,2,2],
     'city': ['Turtig', 'Zurich', 'Zuerich', 'Bern', 'Berne'],
     'city-attribute': ['blue','blue','blue','red','red'],
     'language': ['R','F','D','D','F',],
     'latitude': [47.37536, 47.37536, 47.37536, 46.95558, 46.95558, ],
     'longitude': [8.53764, 8.53764, 8.53764, 7.43863, 7.43863, ],
     })
gdf0 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df['longitude'], df['latitude']))
shape = MultiPolygon(wkt.loads(u'MULTIPOLYGON(((46.2015 6.1463, 46.2215 6.1463, 46.2215 6.1563, 46.20155 6.15630, 46.2015 6.1463)))'))
gdf = gdf0.append({'gid': 3, 'city':'Genève', 'city-attribute': 'yellow', 'language':'F', 'geometry':shape}, ignore_index=True)
gdf.drop(columns=['latitude', 'longitude'], inplace=True)
gdf['wkt'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.wkt) # fun fact, with a WKT string it's working
gdf
```

[image: the GeoDataFrame]

and this is the buggy part which raises the error:

```
gdf_grouped = gdf.groupby(
    by=[e for e in gdf.columns if e not in ('city','language')],
    axis=0,
    as_index=False,
    dropna=False
).aggregate({
    'city': lambda x: tuple(x),
    'language': lambda x: tuple(x)
})
```

Anyone already met (and hopefully solved) this issue?

Please, notice that if I drop the `geometry` column prior to that code, it is working fine:

```
gdf.drop(columns=['geometry'], inplace=True)
# the buggy block of code
gdf_grouped
```

which leads to the following [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html?highlight=geodataframe#geopandas.GeoDataFrame):

[image: the grouped GeoDataFrame]

Comment: This probably has to do with including the shape field in your group by (or at least, you’re not explicitly leaving it out of the grouping). You need to aggregate your geometries or not include it in the grouping.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/725) on github discussing this issue, and then it looks like a fix may have been implemented in the latest version (maybe only the development version). But the problem of how to merge topologically equivalent, but not identically defined shapely objects still stands and it looks like a fix isn't coming soon. you're better off leaving it out and then adding the shape back in (check out [dissolve](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html)) after your groupby.

Comment: Exclude geometry column from by

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Point' and 'Point'

is telling you that `shapely.Point` object are not supporting the "<" operator. this operator is used by Geopandas to order or group.

simply drop the geometry column and then aggregate the point together:

```py
from shapely.ops import unary_union

gdf_grouped = gdf.groupby(
    by=[e for e in gdf.columns if e not in ('city','language', 'geometry')],
    axis=0,
    as_index=False,
    dropna=False
).aggregate({
    'city': lambda x: tuple(x),
    'language': lambda x: tuple(x),
    'geometry': lambda x: unary_union(x)
})

gdf_grouped
```

Comment: I'm actually using `lambda x: x.iloc[0]` or `lambda x: x.unique()[0]` as workarounds, which also work in my case.